# Can I convert any recursion code to a recurrence relation?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

So I have been studying dynamic programming on youtube, here's the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oBt53YbR9Kk&t=4257s, I was studying at the grid traveller recursion section. But I'm still confused about the time complexity.

For example this grid traveller recursion method:

```
int gridTraveler(int m, int n) {
  if (m == 0 || n == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  if (m == 1 || n == 1) {
    return 1;
  }
  return gridTraveler(m - 1, n) + gridTraveler(m, n - 1);
}
```

why the time complexity is O(2^(m+n))? is there any explanation using the recurrence relation?

and also this grid traveller recursion with memoization method:

```
Map<String, int> memo = {};

int gridTraveler(int m, int n) {
  if (m == 0 || n == 0) {
    return 0;                      
  }
  if (m == 1 && n == 1) {
    return 1;                    
  }
  if (memo.containsKey('${m},${n}')) {
    return memo['${m},${n}'] as int;          
  }

  if (memo.containsKey('${n},${m}')) {
    return memo['${n},${m}'] as int;            
  }
  memo['${m},${n}'] = gridTraveler(m - 1, n) + gridTraveler(m, n - 1);  
    return memo['${m},${n}'] as int;                                   
}
```

why the time complexity is O(m*n)? is there any explanation using the recurrence relation?

Answer (score 1):

For grid traveler recursion method **without** memoization method, if we draw the tree it will look something like that

[image]

Here for every node or state, two child nodes/states will be calculated until they reach the base case. so for N= m+n, there will be 2^N nodes or state. So the time complexity is O(2^(N)) or O(2^(n+m))

Now if we look at the tree here we are calculating values of the states that were calculated previously, so values for the same state are calculating many times. With memorizing technique if we calculate a state we save its value and we ever reach a previously calculated state we return the values from the DP table. So we only calculate a state only once, There can be m*n states in the DP table.

[image: DP table]

So the time complexity is O(m*n) with memorizing method

Comment: This is a good answer, but not every node has 2 children in the recursive without-memoization case -- branches of the tree are cut off when n=1 or m=1. It's reasonable to simplify to say that every node has 2 children, and that gives you the upper bound of 2^(m+n). If you don't simplify, you get the more accurate (m+n) choose n.

Comment: can you elaborate what does m*n? is it the possible total nodes? because when I calculate the gridtraveler(3,3) it makes 11 nodes, not 9 nodes?

Comment: apart from the base case, there will be almost n * m nodes with memorizing. Maybe you are calculating the same nodes many times. Suppose, we calculate the gridtraveler(2,2), its value store in the DP table. If we ever again reach gridtraveler(2,2) we don't going to calculate further, we return the value from the DP table. And there is n*m combination. Use pen and paper to visualize. Also don't consider base cases as calculated node